Historical controversy surrounding division of the Tanach into Christian chapters / verses?
What kind of reception did the transition to Christian chapter and verse numbers have within the Jewish world in or around the mid 15th century? Did it stir up any kind of controversy?
Background:
The chapter/verse numbers seem mainly attributed to Stephen Langton (Archbishop of Canterbury) around 1228.
Their first Jewish use seems to have been the concordance of Isaac Nathan in the mid 1400s, most likely for polemical purposes (i.e., text-based religious disputes with Christians), giving this numbering a legitimacy in the Jewish world that it had not enjoyed until then. https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2979/aleph.11.2.289
(I believe the article is free to access if the history of this concordance fascinates you, but you may need to create an account...)
This division has become so standard now, but I can't imagine that everyone just gave it a free pass at the time... (unless the purpose of holding polemics was considered so important and/or the benefit of being able to find perakim / pesukim easily was so great that it was worth embracing this new tradition wholeheartedly?)
First time with a question after 7 years of lurking. Any insights would be most appreciated! THANKS!!
(Related thread looking for a contemporary Tanach that doesn't use non-Jewish divisions (there doesn't seem to be one).
Tanach without Christian chapter divisions)

I would guess it just happened with due to the church vetting all printed material. Is there any preprinting press tanach with chapters? or do jewish writings even quote things based off chapters as opposed to parsha eg "pashat sotah"

His stated purpose, I believe, was the convenience of being able to argue "chapter and verse" with Christian representatives.
Happy to be corrected with sources, of course.

Great question though. How did people "cite" specific pesukim and/or parshiyot (i.e., the older open/closed divisions of the Tanach) before chapter/verse numbers?

The rishonim just cite the parshah eg Parshat Sotah and assume you know where it is. there is only a couple of verses per Parshah, its more exact than citing a daf...

If nobody thought the numbers were trying to be Jewish then they'd be less likely to arouse controversy.

I vaguely remember reading an article in a Mishpacha Kolmus magazine many years ago that discussed this. IIRC the article brought examples of deliberate Chapter breaks that disrupted the narrative in support of Xian arguments. Couldn't find the article online

found this - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136094/36682

This Hebrew Wikipedia article addresses the division of Tanakh into the Christian chapter and verse numbers.
The article confirms that the divisions were to enable text-based religious disputes with Christians.
(translation of parts of the Hebrew Wikipedia article follows):

More than just providing a system of identifying verses, the chapter
and verse divisions reflects the Christian tendency to diminish the
value of the commandments and emphasize the verses Christianity
identified as early prophecies about Jesus.
There are examples of simple misunderstanding of the text and examples
of division with a polemical motive. At the beginning of the book of
Genesis, the Torah begins its stories with the creation of the world,
which lasted six days, and on the seventh day, God rested, thus
commanding the people of Israel to rest on this day. Therefore, the
Hebrew division of the creation story sees the entire story as a
single unit, ending with the sanctification of the Sabbath day. The
Christians, wanting to blur the uniqueness of the Sabbath, moved the
verses about it to the next chapter, along with the story of the
Garden of Eden.
Another clear example is at the beginning of the last chapter of the
book of Hosea (chapter 14). According to the Jewish division, there is
an open section one verse after the start of the Christian chapter
(verse 2): "Return, O Israel, unto the Lord thy God; for thou hast
stumbled in thine iniquity." The message is that after several
chapters of rebuke, Hosea concludes with a call to repentance. The
Christian division, however, starts the chapter with the verse that
was supposed to end the previous chapter: "Samaria shall bear her
guilt, for she hath rebelled against her God: they shall fall by the
sword: their infants shall be dashed in pieces, and their women with
child shall be ripped up." This means that the message is that the
people of Israel have sinned against their God and therefore will be
destroyed. The next verse and onwards speak about the "new people of
Israel" (the Christians).

I could not find evidence of controversy in or around the mid 15th century but it seems reasonable to assume that our Sages objected strongly to this method of changing the sense of Tanakh.

It seems to me that only your last paragraph answers the question, and it's speculation.

I agree. I thought the HeWikipedia was useful background.
